# fadeIn Element On Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I'm trying to make my element, in this case called #position_nav, fade in using jQuery as soon as the user scrolls the page.

Here is the SASS (only used for nesting)

```
#position_nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -75px;
    z-index: 500;
    display: none;

    /* Styling for navigation list */
    ul {list-style: none; padding-left: none; font-size: 14px;}
    li {
        background: #FFF;
        margin: 10px 0 0 -40px;
        cursor: pointer; 
        a {
            /* Formatting for list items */
            &:link {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
            &:hover {color: #CCC;}
            &:active {color: #222;}
            &:visited {text-decoration:none; color: #FFF;}
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
            $("#position_nav").fadeIn("fast");
        };
});
```

I've seen several solutions to using fadeIn in my case, but none seem to work.

EDIT:

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="neo_container"> <!-- Container start -->
            <div id="neo_homeimage">    <!-- Brand statement image -->
                <h1 class="neo_homeimage_text"><?php the_field('home_image_text'); ?></h1>
            </div>  <!-- Brand statement image end -->
            <div id="neo_about_section">    <!-- About section start -->
                <div class="neo_text_container">    <!-- About text container -->
                    <h1>About the Grossman Companies, Inc.</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <div id="neo_about_button"> <!-- Read more button -->
                        <p>Read More</p>
                    </div>  <!-- Read more button end -->
                </div>  <!-- Text container end -->
            </div>  <!-- About section end -->
            <div id="neo_accord_section">   <!-- Accordion section start -->
                <div>
                    <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="radio" />
                    <label for="ac-1">Acquisitions</label>
                    <article class="ac-small">
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="radio" />
                    <label for="ac-2">Private Lending</label>
                    <article class="ac-small">
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="ac-3">Brokerage</label>
                    <article class="ac-small">
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="ac-4">Property Management</label>
                    <article class="ac-small">
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</p>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>  <!-- Accordion section end -->
            <div id="neo_featprop_section"> <!-- Featured poperties section -->
                <div id="neo_featprop_header">  <!-- Featured properties header -->
                    <h1 class="neo_featprop_headertext">Featured Properties</h1>
                </div>  <!-- Featured properties header end -->
                <div id="neo_featprop_gallery"> <!-- Featured properties gallery start -->
                    <!-- First Row -->
                    <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button -->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end -->
                     <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened img overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button -->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end -->
                     <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened img overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button-->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end -->
                    <!-- Second Row -->
                     <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened img overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button-->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end -->
                     <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened img overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button-->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end -->
                     <div class="neo_gall_img">
                        <div class="neo_img_overlay"></div> <!-- Darkened img overlay -->
                        <div class="neo_gall_textcontainer">    <!-- Text container for indiv. gall img -->
                            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <div class="neo_gall_img_button">   <!-- View more button -->
                                <p>View</p>
                            </div>  <!-- View more button-->
                        </div>  <!-- Gall img text container end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Img end --> 
                </div>  <!-- Featured properties gallery end -->
            </div>  <!-- Featured poperties section end -->
            <div id="neo_currnews_section"> <!-- Current news section -->
                <div id="neo_currnews_header">  <!-- Current new header -->
                    <h1 class="neo_currnews_headertext">Current News</h1>
                </div>  <!-- Current news header end-->
                <div id="neo_currnews_content"> <!-- Current news main content -->
                    <div id="neo_currnews_gall">    <!-- Current new gallery -->
                        <div class="neo_currnews_gall_img1">
                            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=310&h=225&bg=0ff&fg=000000" />
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Property Name</h2>
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Leases</h2>
                            <p class="gall_img_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="neo_currnews_gall_img2">
                            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=310&h=225&bg=ff00&fg=000000" />
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Property Name</h2>
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Leases</h2>
                            <p class="gall_img_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="neo_currnews_gall_img3">
                            <img src="http://fpoimagery.com/?t=px&w=310&h=225&bg=0000cc&fg=000000" />
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Property Name</h2>
                            <h2 class="gall_img_text">Leases</h2>
                            <p class="gall_img_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- Curent news gallery end -->
                    <div id="neo_currnews_panel_a"> <!-- Current news expandable info panel -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_header">    <!-- Info panel header -->
                            <h2>News</h2>
                            <h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</h2>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel header end -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_content">   <!-- Info panel content -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Left column -->
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Left column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Middle column -->
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
                                <p>Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Middle column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column2">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel content end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Current news info panel end -->
                    <div id="neo_currnews_panel_b"> <!-- Current news expandable info panel -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_header">    <!-- Info panel header -->
                            <h2>More News</h2>
                            <h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</h2>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel header end -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_content">   <!-- Info panel content -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Left column -->
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Left column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Middle column -->
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
                                <p>Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Middle column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column2">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel content end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Current news info panel end -->
                    <div id="neo_currnews_panel_c"> <!-- Current news expandable info panel -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_header">    <!-- Info panel header -->
                            <h2>News</h2>
                            <h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</h2>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel header end -->
                        <div id="neo_currnews_panel_content">   <!-- Info panel content -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Left column -->
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Left column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column"> <!-- Middle column -->
                                <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
                                <p>Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.</p>
                            </div>  <!-- Middle column end -->
                            <div class="neo_currnews_panel_column2">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>  <!-- Info panel content end -->
                    </div>  <!-- Current news info panel end -->
                </div>  <!-- Current news content end -->
            </div>  <!-- End current news section -->
        </div> <!-- Container end -->
```

Link to site in development http://neoscapelabs.com/projects/grossman_corp/

Comment: In the jQuery you are fading in an element called `neo_position_nav` but in your SASS it looks like it's just labeled `position_nav`. Are you sure you're using the right selector?

Comment: Just changed it, my mistake

Comment: Is this a problem with your JS or with Sass?  If this is a JS problem, it would be more useful to provide the compiled CSS along with the markup.

Comment: what's your `HTML` markup? did all element is inside `#position_nav`, and can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link with your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(window).bind` function is unclosed, it should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
            $("#position_nav").fadeIn("fast");
        };
    });
});
```

Seems to be working once you close it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qx9ud1t4/)

Comment: Thank you for catching that, but it still does not seem to work on my end. I've included my HTML and a link to the site in development into my original post if you could take a look

Comment: Looks like you are getting an `undefined is not a function` error. Are you including jQuery before executing any jQuery functions? Are you using Wordpress? Try using jQuery in no-conflict mode(replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery`) i.e. `$(document).ready(function()` becomes `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you I had no idea. Yeah it's a WordPress site, and I'm still kind of new to it. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, here is some more info on Wordpress and jQuery's noConflict mode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers